# Chrome (Desktop/Emulator/Mobile): window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight issue

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

As of recently (around mid-January 2016) , it seems like `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` is no longer reporting the correct viewport dimension (after pinch-zoom) in Chrome browser. It will always report the device screen size instead...

Does anyone here know if this is a bug with Chrome, or a feature change in their browsers?

This was functioning property before, and it is still is working fine on Safari (desktop/iOS).

Comment: I think this is related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571297

Comment: Thank you ! Not sure the best way to workaround this yet as my project requires exact sizing detection... but will keep an eye on it.